# jquery UI Sortable adding drag image to the drag item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

How to add the drag image to the drag item during dragging?

I used the following code to do the operation

```
$('.selector').sortable({ 
  start: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.item).addClass('dragImage');
  }
 });
```

The class is appending to the dragging item but the image is not applying.

Is their a way to do this

Comment: its probably just taking time to download the image.  You could try putting a hidden div in there that when dragImage is applied to becomes shown

Comment: Do you want to insert an actual image element into the li at start, is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a luck by adding the below code it helps for me

```
$('.selector').sortable({ 
  helper: function(e, tr) {
  var $helper = tr.clone();
  $($helper).addClass('dragRow');
 }
});
```

It may be help full for others.

Answer (score 0):

Rooster: Actually i forgot to mention in that i am using the table and tr. still I tried by appending the div with the class which will have the background-image in css.

```
$(ui.item).append("<div class='dragImage'></div>");
```

But no luck.

Joshua Robinson: i need to add a image on top of the tr or set a background-image for the item that is dragging. So that it will cover the tr item.